# How to store private key on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a flask app hosted on Heroku that needs to run commands on an AWS EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI) using boto.cmdshell.  A couple of questions:

1. Is using a key pair to access the EC2 instance the best practice? Or is using username/password better?
2. If using a key pair is the preferred method, what's the best practice on managing/storing private keys on Heroku? Obviously putting the private key in git is not an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I was looking for was guidance on how to deal with private keys.  Both @DrewV and @yfeldblum pointed me to the right direction.  I ended up turning my private key into a string and storing it in a Heroku config variables.

If anyone is looking to do something similar, here's a sample code snippit using paramiko:

```
import paramiko, base64
import StringIO
import os

key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(StringIO.StringIO(str(os.environ.get("AWS_PRIVATE_KEY"))))
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(str(os.environ.get("EC2_PUBLIC_DNS")), username='ec2-user', pkey=key)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ps')

for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
ssh.close()
```

Thanks to @DrewV and @yfeldblum for helping (upvote for both).

Comment: One more tip: If the secret data is too big to fit in a config variable, encrypt it with AES, put it in a file in your repository, and put the AES key in a config variable instead. If the secret data is an OpenSSL private key, you can instead use its passphrase facility, but make sure the passphrase is a long, completely random string—`secrets.token_hex(16)` should generate something suitable.

Answer (score 7):

Heroku lets you take advantage of [config variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to manage your application. Here is an exmaple of my config.py file that lives inside my flask application:

```
import os

# flask
PORT = int(os.getenv("PORT", 5000))
basedir = str(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = str(os.getenv("APP_SECRET_KEY"))
DEBUG = str(os.getenv("DEBUG"))
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = str(os.getenv("ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"))
TESTING = os.getenv("TESTING", False)

# s3
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = str(os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"))
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = str(os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
S3_BUCKET = str(os.getenv("S3_BUCKET"))
S3_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = str(os.getenv("S3_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY"))
```

Now i can have two different sets of results. It pulls from my [Environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). One when my application is on my local computer and from Heroku config variables when in production. For example.

```
 DEBUG = str(os.getenv("DEBUG"))
```

is "TRUE" on my local computer. But False on Heroku. In order to check your Heroku config run.

```
Heroku config
```

Also keep in mind that if you ever want to keep some files part of your project locally but not in heroku or on github you can use [git ignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files). Of course those files won't exist on your production application then.

Comment: Using `str(os.getenv('SPAM'))` is a big mistake, especially if the settings are required. If `SPAM` isn't configured in the environment, you're setting the values to `"None"`, which is really bad because it will fail in an unexpected way. Use `os.environ['SPAM']` instead, which fail in an obvious way if `SPAM` isn't configured in the environment. If you want the settings to be optional, use `if os.getenv('SPAM') is not None: ...`, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to store config items in an application running on Heroku.

You can use a username/password combination. You may make the username something easy; but be sure to generate a strong password, e.g., with something like `openssl rand -base64 32`.